# Rendering partials each time in each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

I have pages that show to user articles that parsing from rss

There are three models in my app

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :channels

  has_many :feed_articles, through: :channels

  has_many :comments
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :user

  has_many :feed_article
end

class FeedArticle < ActiveRecord::Base     
  belongs_to :channel

  has_many :comments
end
```

This is controller:

```
  def home
    @articles = current_user.try(:feed_articles)
    @comments = current_user.comments
  end
```

This is helpers for view:

```
def take_comments_for(article)
  @comments.select{|f| f["feed_article_id"] == article.id }
end

def what_article(article)
  current_user.comments.build(feed_article_id: article.id)
end
```

And this is view:

```
- if user_signed_in?

    - @articles.each do |article|

          = link_to "#{article.title}",article.link

          = raw article.description
        - if article.favourite?

            = render :partial => "layouts/remove_from_favourite",:locals => { :article =>article }
        - else

            = render :partial => "layouts/add_to_favourite",:locals => { :article => article }
        - if take_comments_for(article).any?

            comments
          - take_comments_for(article).each do |comment|

              = comment.content
        = render :partial => "layouts/add_comment",:locals => { :article => article }
```

I remove html-tags for better view.

And it is partials:

**_add_to_favourite.html.haml**(remove is the same.)

```
= form_for article, remote: true do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :favourite, :value => "true"
  = f.submit "add to favorite", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

**_add_comment.html.haml**:

```
= form_for what_article(article) do |f|
  = f.text_area :content, :rows => 3, :class => "span6", :placeholder => 'Enter text.'
  = f.hidden_field :feed_article_id
  %br
  = f.submit "add comment", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

If I start it, my pages loaded with rendering partials each time for each article,like this:

```
 Rendered layouts/_add_to_favourite.html.haml (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (91.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_to_favourite.html.haml (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_to_favourite.html.haml (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_to_favourite.html.haml (2.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_to_favourite.html.haml (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_add_comment.html.haml (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_remove_from_favourite.html.haml (2.0ms)
```

And page is loading so long.

And if I add partials to my view file, it's ok.

Explain me please, why it's rendering each time( I suppose that it take variable @comments from controller), and how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is rendering each time because you told it to do just that in your each block.
This in and of itself is not liked the cause of your problem.

Your problem most likely revolves around your "take_comments_for".
First, you are calling it twice, once for the if and once to actually display it.

Second, the way you are loading the relations you are hitting an n+1 issue.  You should setup your relationships and your subsequent queries such that you are eagerly loading comments and articles. This will load up the required data up front in 2 calls instead if hitting the DB for every individual item in your each block.